# Ajax call back not called. How to tackle this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, callback

Again I am here for your suggestions. I have some AJAX call for running code from my editor which is a PHP online editor. (You guys can check in [my site](http://web.guru99.com/).)

I have some ajax call for send the data of editor and received output.

Problem: for loop not executed properly.

1. Below for loop program is executed successfully

   ```
   <?php
   for($i=10;$i>1;$i--){
       echo "$i<br>";
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. While this for loop is not executed

   ```
   <?php
   for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
   {
       echo "The number is: $x <br>";
   }
   ?>
   ```

When I run this through FireBug, I get a response saying that the for loop has become an infinite loop in case of second loop (above).

Now here is my AJAX callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'exec.php',
    data: code,
    success: function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);
        $(loader).addClass("hidden");
        var stdout = $(form).children('.stdout');
        if (data.search("Parse error")>0)
        {
            var str = data.replace("<b>Parse error</b>:  ","");
        $(stdout).html(str);
        $(stdout).removeClass('hidden');    
        }   
        else
        {
            $(stdout).html(data);
            $(stdout).removeClass('hidden');
        }   
    },
    error: function(req, status, err) {
        alert(status);
        alert(err);
    },
    dataType: 'JSONP'
});
```

I have re-implemented this editor locally and run it; In FireBug I am getting this error:

> Error: jQuery110106354119750428449_1386321122498 was not called

here is my JSON callback code from the server:

```
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($script_output).");";
```

Please help me to tackle this error.

Comment: I seriously doubt you're debugging PHP with Firebug. It is very unclear what you're trying to achieve as you mix PHP and Javascript without any obvious link between the 2

Comment: why are you setting `dataType:'JSONP'`?

Comment: do you mean about two for loops? if yes then please first go to web.guru99.com you can see there i am implementing php code editor. So php code is not concern at all, and

Comment: Actually all code are running only problem is of for loop. You can check here - http://web.guru99.com/. Only this for loop is not running so i am not sure what is the issue but by error of ajax call shows this Error: jQuery110106354119750428449_1386321122498 was not called

Comment: it looks to me like that codeguru site has a bug with its PHP interpreter, that loop should not have a problem

Comment: I am solving that bug

Comment: you mean you are developing the http://web.guru99.com/ website?

Comment: yes i am developing the code editor for that site and i think you have to take personal intrest because so many beginner can learn from there

Comment: i guess it is a server side error

Comment: i don't think so because i had check the code in morning line by line but i think when json calback is run (echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($script_output).");";) this error generates

Comment: I think too that this is a server siede error. It's an endless loop with `for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
    echo "$i<br>";
}` this seems to give you problems: **<** as this works: **>**

Comment: Answer of server: some MB big...
0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0<br>0 ... and so on...

Comment: @SanjayRathod So if this code generate the error, the error is on server, not client side.

Comment: After checking, looks like this is '++' which creates kind of infinite loop. '++' doesn't increment referenced variable so this gives you infinite loop

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes error is on server side, Do you think is there any problem with json call back code echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($script_output).");";. I think the error is there only because i had check the server side code and if i remove this code the output is correct

Comment: @SanjayRathod check what give you: `json_encode($script_output)`

Comment: @A.Wolff that gives the output of code enters in editor

Comment: I am run the php code through eval method of php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42639/discussion-between-sanjay-rathod-and-a-wolff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]After some test's, i thing the problem are the `++` in the url, try to encode:

```
encodeURIComponent
```

as this worked for me:

```
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x%2B%2B)
  {
  echo "The number is: $x <br>";
  }
```

...

```
+ = %2B
```

the server got this:
($x=0; $x<=10; $x )
so it is infinite loop, as $x stays 0

Comment: Brother thanks for your reply but this transfers error for run other codes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42637/discussion-between-sanjay-rathod-and-reyaner)

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with

```
<?php
$opstr = "";
for ($x=0; $x<=10; $x++)
 {
   $opstr .= "The number is: $x <br>";
 }
echo $opstr;
exit();
?>
```

And try to execute your ajax call again.