# How to tackle infinite loop?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, callback, codemirror

Hi all here you can check my previous question - [Ajax call back not called. How to tackle this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420255/ajax-call-back-not-called-how-to-tackle-this)
please check and see here my code of execute.php where the code of editor is goes and run and suggest me why for loop goes to infinite loop.

here is my code of code1.js by that i am fetch code of editor and run through exec.php

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'exec.php',
    data: code,
    success: function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);
        $(loader).addClass("hidden");
        var stdout = $(form).children('.stdout');
        if (data.search("Parse error")>0)
        {
            var str = data.replace("<b>Parse error</b>:  ","");
        $(stdout).html(str);
        $(stdout).removeClass('hidden');    
        }   
        else
        {
            $(stdout).html(data);
            $(stdout).removeClass('hidden');
        }   
    },
    error: function(req, status, err) {
        alert(status);
        alert(err);
    },
    dataType: 'JSONP'
});
```

when i am insert the code of for loop in editor its goes to infinite loop like

";
}
?>

you can check this issue at web.guru99.com

Please help

Comment: Please edit this question to include the code for your loop.

Comment: the jQuery docs say : " In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout;" so are you sure it's  a loop and not just taking a while?    What if you call this directly as a unit test what response do you get?   is the request getting sent over and over again? or does firebug just show one request?  does the output contain an ajax request cuz the final echo might be re-calling that page if it does.

Comment: No in firebug it shows only one request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insteading of posting the PHP code through the url, you can `post` it as additional data. That solves your encoding issues, and it allows you to send larger chunks of code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to `+` sign that is getting misinterpreted when it reaches the server. I think `+` is being replaced by single whitespace which is creating problem in `for` loop. So, `$x++` will be interpreted as `$x` (two whitespaces after `$x`) and it will create an infinite loop.

To get around this problem, you should probably replace all `+` signs in the input code with some symbol using `javascript` and use you own method to `urldecode` on server side.